# Customized clean Views page output

Tags: 7, views, blocks

**Is it possible to get Views to return only block data markup and nothing else?**

I am trying to get the block data via AJAX and place it exactly where I want it.
I just wonder if I can filter way all the surrounding HTML markup.

I have looked into the Output theme for my View but the markup is only for the data generated rather than for the entire page so I can't edit it there.

I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Yes, you probably can. If you want know *how*, consider rewording your question and adding your attempts and approaches you have tried already.